# Why does IdSMTP.Send fail if only one email address is incorrect?

Tags: delphi, smtp, indy

I'm using Indy and Delphi to send email messages.  I've had no issues until one of the users was recently let go.  Their email account was deleted and my program attempted to email about seven users including the "downsized" user.  I expected the SMTP server to accept the email and deliver the message to the valid users and then send an email back to the Sender informing them that the one account in the recipients list is no longer valid.

Instead the SMTP server did not accept anything and no one received the message.  I got "Mailbox Unavailable" in my log.  Is there a setting to change this behavior on my end?  Email clients like Outlook certainly do not behave this way.

Specifically, what is the proper technique to send messages so that all valid email addresses in the recipients lists get delivery, and the Sender is notified by the SMTP server of any incorrect addresses?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Indy 10 then you need to assign a handler to the `TIdSMTP.OnFailedRecipient` event and have it set the `VContinue` parameter to True.

```
procedure TForm1.IdSMTP1FailedRecipient(Sender: TObject; const AAddress, ACode,
  AText: string; var VContinue: Boolean);
begin
  // do something...
  VContinue := True;
end;
```

That will allow `TIdSMTP` to skip the failed recipient and keep sending the email to the remaining recipients.  Only if all of the recipients fail will `TIdSMTP` then fail the send (unless some other non-recipient error occurs, of course).

If you are using Indy 9 or earlier, or do not provide an `OnFailedRecipient` handler, `TIdSMTP` will fail and abort the send on the first error encountered, including a recipient error.

The SMTP server will **NOT** send a notification to the sender's inbox if it actively rejects a given recipient while the email message was still in process of being given to the server by the sender.  You will have to use the `OnFailedRecipient` event to act upon that recipient.  Only recipients that are accepted by the server and then later found to be in error will then send a notification to the sender's inbox accordingly.  That is simply how SMTP works.

Comment: Remy thank you for the comprehensive answer.  I implemented the event handler and then tested it with one valid and one invalid address; however, the SMTP server accepted the message and sent back an email stating the one address was invalid as I originally expected.  Then I tried it using the terminated employee's address as the invalid address and the event handler fired.  It appears the account still exists, but the admin disabled the account, hence the error.  My program can now handle this issue. Thank you.

Comment: If the SMTP server knows right away that the recipient is bad, it will reject it and `OnFailedRecipient` will trigger. But if the server does not know right away (it has to look up the recipient's DNS, has to forward to another server, etc) then it will accept the recipient, thus `OnFailedRecipient` will not trigger, but you will get an error email at a later time if the recipient fails.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau - can you provide some code please on how the handler should be implemented with 'continue' routine ? I cant find anything usable on the net. Thank you.

Comment: @user763539 I thought I was clear when I said "*set the VContinue parameter to True*", but I have updated my answer to show it